# Extract the movie.json.1 (extension (.1) ) using java

Tags: java, json

```
    File file = new File("D:\\final\\movie.json.1");
    String resp = readFile(file);

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(resp);
```

But its giving as a the below exception  :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

movie.json.1 :
Sample text :

> [{"id":"episode_45747","resourceId":"45747","docType":"episode","uniqueName":"45747","locale":["eng"],"filter_locale":["eng"],"filter_device":

This works If the text copy from `.json.1` file to `.txt` file.

Please help me to extract that this type of extension files.

Comment: You can print resp to check if the readFile is correct.

Comment: Do you have a _valid_ JSON in the file you're trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using JSON parser?

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\final\\movie.json.1"));
```

Comment: Thanks for giving response .
but after using this parser i am getting the below error
Exception in thread "main" Unexpected character ( ) at position 1.

Comment: @SreenuPyla Can you share the contents of `movie.json.1`? the sample txt you provided is not a valid JSON. Surely it will fail.